# Lindley equation does not generate a tight sequence of measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider Lindley Equation $X_{t+1} = \max \{X_{t} + V_{t+1},0\}$ on $[0,\infty)$ with an initial state $X_{1} = x$ for $x > 0$ and $V_{t}$ is a sequence of IID random variables.

Assume that there is $a > 0$ with the property that $\mathbb{P}(V_{t} \geq a) > 0$. I need to prove that the sequence of measures $\mu_{t}$ where $\mu_{t}$ is the law of $X_{t}$ is not tight.

$\mu_{t}$ is called tight if for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there is a compact set $[0,M]$ such that $\mu_{t}([0,M]) \geq 1- \epsilon $ for all $t$.

Not sure how show this.